# SnowSight Inserting Random Characters

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've noticed strange behavior in the snowsight console recently, where random `,` characters will be inserted when un-commenting large blocks of code.

[A demo of the random character insertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fi1F.gif)

I'm not sure if this is a bug with snowsight or if something is horribly misconfigured with my editor. I can confirm that I am not hitting the `,` key accidentally while doing this (and even had my coworker watch while I pressed the `ctrl+/` hotkey to make sure I wasn't going insane). I've only noticed this behavior on large multi-line queries like the `COPY INTO` statement shown above. I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this, and if so if there is an official bug report forum for snowflake.

Comment: Did you share your code with your co-worker to reproduce this behavior? And if you paste your code to a new worksheet, do you still see this happening?

Comment: Yep, this has been reproducible across accounts and worksheets on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any bug report on this, but I'm able to reproduce the issue. It is somehow related to the content you uncomment. Please submit a bug report on it.

The following statement is enough to repro the issue:

```
-- COPY INTO xyz
-- FROM (SELECT * FROM abc)
-- FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME=ABC)
-- SINGLE = TRUE
-- HEADER = TRUE
-- OVERWRITE = TRUE;
```

If the above statement is selected **from down to up**, and then used the uncomment shortcut, Snowsight adds a comma at the beginning.

[image: selected text]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know where I would go to submit a bug report to Snowflake?

Comment: @aidanb1409 Pls check this link: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Submit-a-Support-Case-in-Snowflake-Lodge

Comment: Accepting as answer since it's a bug and not a configuration issue. Thank you!